# Can a non-discrete metric $d$ be always defined on any non-empty set $X$ such that $(X,d)$ becomes a complete metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces

Can a non-discrete metric $d$ be always defined on any non-empty set $X$ such that $(X,d)$ becomes a complete metric space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For finite sets, no, since a $T_1$ finite set is discrete, and metric spaces are $T_1$.

But for infinite sets, yes.

First note that there are countable complete metric spaces. For example $\{0\}\cup\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N^+\}$ is a complete metric space under the usual metric from $\Bbb R$.

If $X$ is an infinite set, then we can partition $X$ to $X_i$ such that every part is countable. For each $X_i$ fix a bijection with some non-discrete countable complete metric space, and declare that $d(x,y)=42$ for $x,y$ coming from different parts of $X$.

Of course you can just pick one convergent sequence, and the rest can be isolated points. But that's cheating, in some sense.

If you want no isolated points, then you need to allow the cardinality of $X$ to be at least $2^{\aleph_0}$, then the same trick as above can be applied, by partitioning $X$ into sets of size continuum and using $[0,1]$ as the complete metric space.

Comment: $d(x,y)=42$ !??

Comment: Any constant positive number would suffice, since it ensures that a Cauchy sequence must be (up to finitely many members) all from the same $X_i$.

Comment: By saying $x,y$ coming from different parts of $X$ do you mean $x,y$ belong to different $X_i$'s ? if so then what about $d(x,y)$ when $x,y \in X_i$ ? and you certainly mean $d(x,y)=42$ when $x \ne y$ right ?

Comment: Yes, different parts means different $X_i$'s. If both come from the same $X_i$, use the bijection with the complete metric space to determine their distance.

Comment: but can't a non-discrete metric give a discrete topology ?

Comment: What is your definition of a discrete metric, and what is the definition of a discrete topology?

Comment: Well a topology is discrete iff every set is open . And my definition of discrete metric is $d(x,y)=c(>0) $ for $x \ne y$ and $d(x,x)=0$

Comment: In this case, yes, a non-discrete metric can give a discrete topology, just consider $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$. But if there is a convergent sequence which is not eventually constant, which is exactly what we have here, is the topology discrete?

Comment: If I partition $X$ into non-singleton subsets ; and since they have bijections with finite subsets of $\mathbb R$ ; if I define the metric as you did by detrmining with bijection and transfering the usual distance metric of $\mathbb R$ , will it also not make $X$ complete ? since every finite subset of the reals are complete with usual metric ...

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the discrete metric $d(x,y)=1$ for all $x\ne y$ and $d(x,x)=0$ is complete, simply because any Cauchy sequence is eventually constant.

Yes, for infinite sets this can be done so that the induced topology is not the discrete one. All you need is one complete metric space for every infinite cardinality. Then given any set $X$, take a bijection of it with any complete metric space and transfer the metric. Non-discrete complete metric spaces of any infinite cardinality are easy to manufacture. For instance, using $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean topology, which is complete, you can easily produce a complete metric on any cardinality larger than it.

Comment: Sorry ; I meant to be non-discrete metric , I have edited .

Comment: Then what about finite non-empty sets ?

Comment: what about them? do you want a non-discrete metric on them???